# Hypervisor hidden boxes are appearing on the screen

Tags: drivers, virtual-machine, display, hypervisor

For a while on my hypervisor I've been noticing hidden boxes in the background of the screen.  At first they we're very subtle to the point where I was questioning whether they existed or not.

But recent I was watching a video and I saw them vividly.

Hidden Boxes:
[image: Hidden Boxes]

Highlighted what I see in blue
[image: Hidden Boxes Highlighted]

However when I watch the same video on my machine without going through the hypervisor everything looks fine

No Hidden Boxes:
[image: No Hidden Boxes]

**Note:** I just noticed that the screen shot probably won't help. Since they both have boxes on my hypervisor and none have boxes on my main machine.

I'm very confused, I'm guess this is driver related? Any insight on how to fix

Comment: Can you edit the images to indicate these "hidden boxes"?

Comment: I just did, each picture has different hidden boxes in them even the blue highlighted one has more hidden iridescent boxes in other areas

Comment: It’s not a driver issue. The boxes don’t appear in your screenshots

Comment: @Ramhound what could cause it. they're more prevalent on the hypervisor.